# VS2012 built Windows Application Crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After building my application in `VS2012 Update 4` , my application started crashing with the below mentioned problem signature.

```
Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name: BEX64
 Application Name: App.exe
 Application Version: 1.0.0.1
 Application Timestamp: 52fdbd9d
 Fault Module Name: MSVCR110.dll
 Fault Module Version: 11.0.51106.1
 Fault Module Timestamp: 5098826e
 Exception Offset: 000000000006d4f9
 Exception Code: c0000417
 Exception Data: 0000000000000000
 OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1: 1032
 Additional Information 2: 103247eabca85d12954263c679d66e19
 Additional Information 3: 7fa2
 Additional Information 4: 7fa2470b0fea6279055c0db583abca71
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tried re installing but no luck,issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

The module that is crashing is from "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4". Reading some posts online it seems that the problem can possibly be solved by reinstalling it.

You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging your application?

BEX64 is supposed to mean that your application is trying to execute code from memory pages that contain data and not instructions.

It is almost certainly not a bug in the VS 2012 runtime library, but a fatal bug in your program, which you will have to debug.

This could be caused by a buffer overflow, if writing data past the end of a subroutine's local data buffer overwrote the routine's return address.  (This is how one class of viruses works)

Or it could be caused by trashing an object's virtual function pointer table.

For more information, Google DEP or Data Execution Prevention.